# Windows: unable to open files created (using python script ) in nested folders

Tags: windows, powershell

I am creating nested folders and creating files in that folders using python script, It's structure is like this: for ex depth=40

```
Dir1/Dir2/.../Dir40
```

I want to give long directory name like: Dir<dir_counter><any random 10 chars>
Now I am able to create that folders successfully from python script (python script doesn't through any error)but

1. Not able to open files present in 16th (approximately) folders
2. Not able to open 20th folder (approximately)

It gives following error when I try to open file/folder **in windows explorer**:
[image]

I have enabled :

1. Longpaths from

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem from
2. Also enabled `Win 32 long path` from group policy.
3. NtfsAllowExtendedCharacter8dot3Rename

Two additional cases:

1. when I am giving only character as directory name then I am able to open it in windows explorer
2. **Able to open any file from PowerShell** having long nested path.

what should I do to open everything from windows explorer?

Comment: Have you tried using the Windows long path prefix `"\\?\"`?

Comment: Could you add a sample code snippet which shows how you try to open the files?

Comment: @BoarGules This prefix is not tried yet, I will check

Comment: Tried using Windows long path prefix "\\?\", but that is also not working

Comment: @schilli I am only creating files and folders using scripts and when I try to open that file having long nested path, it is giving me an issue

So for opening file, no code is there
and for creating folders using `os.makedirs`

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you mean by *not working*? Please show the code you are executing, the exact value of the path you are trying to open, and the full error trace. That is the part that begins with the line `Traceback (most recent call last):` and ends with the error message. *Edit* your question (link bottom left next to Share) to include this information: don't put it in a comment.